# How can I add a new recipient to a Facebook message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I've sent a message in Facebook to multiple people. I want to send another one to the same group without adding them one by one, but just add one new person instead. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in Facebook. It's **by design**.

Comment: Did they officially say it's by design?

Comment: There is no need to hear an official statement that tells "We don't have this feature". What you ask is a feature request and they don't have it at the moment.

Comment: You can submit this as a suggestion for Facebook using [this](http://www.facebook.com/#!/help/?topic=suggestions) page.

Comment: I've sent a message in Facebook to multiple people. I want to send another one to the same group without adding them one by one, but just add one new person instead. Is there a way to do this? Darn, i have the same problem as above. Cousins from all over the world were chatting about lives before, I need to add one more cousin, i wish i FB has this application :-(.

Answer (score 2):

In the message at the top right there is an actions button with an 'add people' option.

I seem to have a newer version of the message function (as it keeps telling me most of my friends don't and I should invite them). So sorry if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, click actions and then open in chat  you can add people.
[image: "open in chat"]

Comment: Where to open it? Perhaps you can through in a screenshot?

Comment: Image added, maybe you have to enable chat first?